# Como saber que boton del mouse fue presionado

Tags: javascript, html, eventos, mouse

Deseo saber cuando se presione un boton del mouse sobre el `button`, cual fue el presionado, si el izquierdo, derecho, o el de en medio. El problema es que para el click derecho me sale el tipico menu. Tampoco detecta si presiono el de en medio. ¿Como detectar también si fue apretado uno aparte del izquierdo?, y ¿como ocultar el menu que sale por defecto al apretar click derecho?

```js
 function handleOnClick(e) {
     console.log("button clicked");
     console.log(e.button);
 }
```

```html
<button onclick="handleOnClick(event)">
    myButton
</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternativamente puedes usar un listener directamente en el botón al click (el botón puede ser cualquier tag HTML):

```js
    document.getElementById("boton").addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
      console.log(e.which);
    });
```

```html
    <button id="boton">Este también es un botón</button>
```

Esto arroja en la consola el botón que estás presionando.

**Edit:**

Se ha cambiado el listener de click a mousedown. Ahora detecta todos los botones que se presionan arrojando el resultado en consola. No se usa JQuery.

Comment: Ayudaría un comentario para saber la causa de los downvotes cada que existen para así corregir en todo caso lo que sea necesario corregir.

La solución que presento es sencilla y limpia.

Answer (score 2):

Con este código sabrás que tipo de click realizó, con JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#id").mousedown(function(ev){
        //1 - izquierdo; 2 - medio; 3 - derecho
            if(ev.which == 3) 
                {
                 $('#mensaje1').text("se oprimió el botón derecho");
                }
        });
});
```

Para saber con Javascript:

```html
<html>
<body >
  <input type="button" onmousedown="detectarBoton(event);" value="BOTON">
<script>
function detectarBoton(event){
 
 if (event.button==2)
  alert("El botón del ratón pulsado fue el derecho");
 else if (event.button==1)
  alert("El botón del ratón pulsado fue el medio");
     else
  alert("El botón del ratón pulsado fue el izquierdo");
 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si puedes pon el ejemplo en javascript. Y en un snippet para poder ejecutar mas facilmente el codigo ;)

Comment: Te  coloqué un ejemplo

Comment: @Carlos tu solución para JS está detectando clicks en todo el documento, no en el botón.

Comment: Ya modifiqué, le agregué al botón, estaba algo desatento jajaja

Answer (score 2):

```html
<html>
<body >
  <input type="button" onmousedown="detectarBoton(event);" value="BOTON">
<script>
function detectarBoton(event){
 
 if (event.button==2)
  alert("El botón del ratón pulsado fue el derecho");
 else if (event.button==1)
  alert("El botón del ratón pulsado fue el medio");
     else
  alert("El botón del ratón pulsado fue el izquierdo");
 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Deberias unificar las respuestas si no dan distintas soluciones de resolver el problema. Ademas, al presionar la rueda del mouse (boton del medio) me loguea click izquierdo igual. Y en el derecho me sigue sacando el menu

Comment: Ahí te arregle. Una respuesta fue con JQuery, la cual no era lo que estabas buscando aunque se podría solucionar de esa manera(JQuery = Javascript), y esta, que es netamente Javascript

Comment: Luego del `alert` sigue saliendo el menu del click derecho, hay alguna forma de prevenir esto?

Comment: Bastante raro, estoy probando ahora mismo el ejemplo, haciendo click derecho sobre el botón aparece la alerta, le doy ciclk (izquierdo) sobre Aceptar, y no aparece el ningún menú

Comment: @Carlos, considera eliminar esta segunda respuesta, para favorecer la anterior

Answer (score 0):

Que tal, mira para poder hacerlo de una manera sencilla puedes agregar la librería de jQuery a tu proyecto como en el ejemplo que te voy a dejar. Esta librería contiene funciones habituales que ya son un estándar y puedes aprovecharlo para realizar lo que necesitas asignando un listener a un elemento de tu HTML y en el solo poner los if necesarios o bien un switch para realizar algo cada que el código del Click sea igual al que tu necesitas.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      /*La variable Event que se envia en la funcion es
       **para capturar todo el evento el cual lleva el
       **caracter precionado es un JSON*/
      $("#label").click(function(event) {
        switch (event.which) {
          case 0:
            $(this).html("click tipo: medio");
            break;
          case 1:
            $(this).html("click tipo: izquierdo");
            break;
          case 2:
            $(this).html("click tipo: derecho");
            break;
        }
      });

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <button id="label">Esperando Click</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hola. Tu codigo me detecta solo cuando aprieto el izquierdo, y cuando lo hago con el derecho  me sigue sacando el menu. Igual, esperaba una respuesta usando solo javascript