# Error php al presionar un boton

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

Buenas, soy nuevo en php.
Tengo una duda con el botón de mi pagina. Al momento de dar click al boton, no me muestra nada, pero en mi codigo, si esta configurado para ver si se presiona o no.
Cuando uso el signo de interrogacion delante del isset, si me capta el click, pero no entiendo prq. Por lo que estube viendo, cuando es isset.. me dice que el boton si fue presionado, pero cuando es !isset me indica que el boton no fue presionado.

```css
.boxlogin{
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px #d6d6d6;
    margin: 75px auto;
    width: 320px;
    -webki-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
   }
   .btn{
    margin-top: 14px;
   }
```

```html
 
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charser="UTF-8">
 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Document</title>
  
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
 <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="~/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 

</head>
<body>
 <header>
</header>

<div class="jumbotron boxlogin">
   
  <form method="POST" name="flogin" id="flogin" action="">
  <label>Usuario:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username"     class="form-control">
  <label>Contraseña:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password"    class="form-control">

   

  <button name="btnClickI" type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ingreso">Ingresar</button> 
  <a href="registro.php"><button value="btnClickR" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Registrar</button></a>
   
    
   <?php  
   if(isset($_GET['btnClickI'])){
    if( !isset($_POST['username'])  or  !isset($_POST['password']) ) {           
           echo '<div id="ingreso" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-diolag">
        <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
          <h3>Por favor llene todo los campos!</h3>          
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
            </div>';
    }else{
    }
   } 
   ?>
  </form>
 </div>

 <script type="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: por favor no pongas una imagen de tu codigo, pega el codigo en la pregunta.

Comment: Disculpa, ahi lo subì.

Answer (score 0):

El `method` del formulario es `POST` y tratas de recibir la variable por `GET` por lo que nunca va a estar definida.

Comment: Le cambie a GET, por que con POST no me funcionaba. Pero es igual :(

Comment: Pero username si esta definido por lo que no se cumple la segunda condicion.

Answer (score 0):

estás mezclando métodos; GET y POST en un mismo script. Básicamente le dices a PHP que si encuentra la variable `btnClickI` que llegó por el método GET entonces busque usuario y contraseña por el método POST; esto no se puede hacer.

En tu script he cambiado tus isset por un `if` que revisará si fue GET o POST y entonces imprimirá un listado de las variables que estás enviando. con esto puedes entonces saber que buscas con isset y estar seguro de que sí está llegando la info que buscas:

```css
.boxlogin{
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px #d6d6d6;
    margin: 75px auto;
    width: 320px;
    -webki-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
   }
   .btn{
    margin-top: 14px;
   }
```

```html
 
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charser="UTF-8">
 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Document</title>
  
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 

</head>
<body>
 <header>
</header>

<div class="jumbotron boxlogin">
   
  <form method="POST" name="flogin" id="flogin" action="">
  <label>Usuario:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username"     class="form-control">
  <label>Contraseña:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password"    class="form-control">

   

  <button name="btnClickI" type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ingreso">Ingresar</button> 
  <a href="registro.php"><button value="btnClickR" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Registrar</button></a>
<div id="ingreso" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-diolag">
        <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
          <h3>Por favor llene todo los campos!</h3>          
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
   
    
   <?php  
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
                              var_dump($_POST);
           echo '<h2>Había una vez un código HTML...</h2>';
    }else{

                     echo '<h1>ESTO ES UN GET</h1>';
                     var_dump($_GET);
    }
   ?>
          </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDICIÓN:**

Si necesitas saber cuando se hizo click a un elemento en específico es más fácil hacerlo con JavaScript: [aquí escribí una respuesta para este problema.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/88390/como-saber-que-boton-del-mouse-fue-presionado/88408#88408)

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Hice los cambios pero no me muestra el modal, me tendria que mostrarlo al momento de dar click en el boton de ingresar :/

Comment: El modal está dentro del bloque POST y para cuando existe un POST ya no hay nada que active el modal.
Tendrías que colocar el moadal **fuera** del bloque POST. Actualizo mi respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Pruebalo así:

```
<div class="jumbotron boxlogin">

        <form method="POST" name="flogin" id="flogin" action="">
            <label>Usuario:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username"     class="form-control">
            <label>Contraseña:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password"    class="form-control">

            <button name="btnClickI" type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ingreso">Ingresar</button> 
            <a href="registro.php"><button value="btnClickR" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Registrar</button></a>

        </form>
    </div>

    <?php    
    if(isset($_POST['btnClickI'])){
      if( !isset($_POST['username'])  or  !isset($_POST['password']) ) {                
                           echo '<div id="ingreso" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-diolag">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <h3>Por favor llene todo los campos!</h3>                                    
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>';
        }else{
        }
    } 
    ?>
```

Comment: mmm me es igual, pero cuando pongo el !isset de esa forma, si me capta el click, pero luego cuando quiero guardar el valor de una variable por metodo POST me manda error que no esta definido la variable? :S